# Java Logger for Arduino

Tags: java, logging, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino logger written in Java.

I have started using the example code from the Arduino playground at:

http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java

My problem is here I think:

```
if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            int available = input.available();
            byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
            input.read(chunk, 0, available);


            // Displayed results are codepage dependent
            String print = new String(chunk);
            test.write(print);
            System.out.print(print);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
```

I wrote a class that will write the data to a csv file. When it prints the data to the console it is perfect. When I write it to the file I get some perfect lines and sometimes bad lines like:

```
60
4

5
28
```

I want it to print it like:

```
604
528
```

My write method is:

```
public void write(String print)
{

    pw.print(System.currentTimeMillis());
    pw.print(",");
    pw.println(print);
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write about printing data on the console and in a file, you do not do exactly the same thing. You print raw data on the console, so you do not see any problems, while you process your data in your write() method which may make some problems appear.

The problem is not in your write() method, but rather the way you use it. As soon as you have some data, you print it. The thing is, you may have not receive all the data, so you print it too early.

It is quite common in data stream: the operating system warns you when data are available, but it may have receive only (let's say) 3 bytes out of 5 sent by the Arduino when it warns you. The operating system cannot know by itself that you were waiting 5 bytes and not only 3.

So you have to store and concatenate your data until you know it was all received. Two possibilities for that:

- If you know that n bytes will be sent, store data until you received n bytes
- Wait for a character flag indicating the end of your data: I suppose you use the Serial.println() method in Arduino, it means that the end of your data will have "\r\n" at the end. Incidentally, it is why you have some new lines in your file when printing data since you did not tell Jave to create new lines :-)

The code could be better, but to keep it simple since I am not sure of your level in Java, and to keep your code, you could do something like that (warning, I did not tested it):

```
// Should be outside of your serialEvent method
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            int available = input.available();
            byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
            input.read(chunk, 0, available);

            // We store data in a buffer
            buffer.append(new String(chunk));
            // We check if we received the characters indicating
            // the end of your data
            int endOfLineIndex = buffer.indexOf("\r\n");
            // We don't, so we leave and wait for more data
            if (endOfLineIndex == -1) { 
                return;
            }

            // The "+2" is to keep the "\r\n"
            String print = buffer.substring(0, endOfLineIndex+2);
            // Do not forget to remove what was used in the buffer
            buffer.delete(0, endOfLineIndex+2);

            test.write(print);
            System.out.print(print);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}
```

By the way, if you do not see any problems when directly printing data in your console, it is because the new lines characters comes from the Arduino and not the Java code. So you print a stream of data that is not broke, because you insert nothing between the characters you print on the screen. In your example, you first receive "60", then "4\r\n". It is a kind of automatic concatenation on the screen.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect !! I'm just wondering what's the "\r", I thought the "\n" created the new line.

Comment: A legacy. In old mechanical typewriters, you had to go back to the beginning of the current line (\r), and then go to a new line (\n). On computers, the encoding of a new line depends according to the operating system: usually \r\n for windows ("like" old typewriters), \r for old Macs, \n for unix-like operating system. But it is a convention before all. You could use only \n for your protocol between Arduino and your computers, it is up to you. But by default, using Serial.println() will add a \r\n.